# Azure DevOps. Can't Create New Hosted Agent Pool

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to add an additional Agent Pool with Hosted Agents into Azure DevOps. How can we do that? When I click "Add pool" button there is no option to add Hosted Agent type of Agent Pool, only Self-hosted or Azure virtual machine scale set.
[image]
I need to do that, because there are 2 Pipelines that always must have access to 1 Hosted Agent. That agent should never be used outside of these 2 Pipelines. And in case if these 2 Pipelines are queued at the same time, one of them must wait for the Hosted Agent to complete the second Pipeline.
I wanted to achieve that by having separate Agent pool and referencing it by:

```
pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines 2'
```

Comment: You can't. There is one hosted agent pool. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I explained why I want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add new hosted agent pool. But you can increase the number of hosted agents by purchasing additional parallel jobs in workspace Settings > Pipelines > Parallel jobs.

[image]